# Jquery radio button check

Tags: jquery

I want to check is there any radio button selected and if there is no selection to print some alert message.

The html code is:

```
<form action="" id="form" name="form" method="post">
<input type="radio" id="form_rd" name="form_rd" value="1"> 1
<input type="radio" id="form_rd" name="form_rd" value="2"> 2
<input type="radio" id="form_rd" name="form_rd" value="3"> 3
<button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Jquery that I'm using for checking:

```
$("form#form").submit(function() {
if (!$("#form_rd").attr('checked')) {alert("not checked");return false;}
})
```

This jquery code is not working. What is the better solution for this radio button check?

Comment: change id="form_rd" to class="form_rd" first!

Comment: Agreed. You're messing with the browser's mind.

Answer (score 5):

I cannot emphasize enough that **IDs *must* be unique**! So change your `id="form_rd"` into (for example) `class="form_rd"`. Leave `name` alone, however, because the receiving end won't like the request if you change that too.

Try

```
$("form#form").submit(function() {
    if ($("#form :radio:checked").length == 0) {
        alert("not checked");
        return false;
    }
});
```

This will fail if you have multiple groups. Do you need a solution for that?

Comment: @MvanGeest - Thanks. I tried with this but keep getting alert message "not checked" even if the radio button is checked?!

Comment: Well, your form's ID is `form`, so I corrected that in the example. Try again. If it still doesn't work, show us some more HTML. (Or do you have multiple forms? All with the ID `form`? Then that's the problem.)

Comment: @MvanGeest - Here is the example link:
http://jsfiddle.net/4kEqx/

I don't have multiple forms. Just one.

Comment: This works: http://jsfiddle.net/HVJpZ/ (the error you see means that the form was submitted) I messed up the jsFiddle history, sorry for that.

Comment: If this answered your question, could you accept the answer? (Not that there's currently another answer that could confuse future visitors, but still.)